# Add drop shadow to image in Keynote slide?

Tags: keynote

I've seen Keynote slides with drop shadows on images.

[image]

How do I do this? I'm using Keynote 6.0.

Comment: Feel free to add a link to a picture posted online (even upload the picture to a online site such as imgur and post a link) and someone with enough rep will embed it. I've added a picture to an image with a drop shadow — feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert your image.
2. Open the Format inspector.

   [image]
3. Click the disclosure triangle next to Shadow to open the section.
4. Select the type of drop shadow you wish and customise it if necessary.

   [image]